# How to get Identifier from User UID

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

In my android application, I have user UID(it is not a current user) so on this UID I want to get Identifier (Phonenumber) from this userID.
I tried lots of links but did not found any working solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What exactly have you tried in code that doesn't work the way you expect? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: I have an app where I am showing 2 markers on my MAP. First marker is user itself and another is target user. So here I can read the Phonenumber of First Market FirebaseUser ref = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            String PhoneNumber = ref.getPhoneNumber();
           Log.d("phonenumber", PhoneNumber);  But i need the phonenumber of another user and I have his User UID only